# Does MC work independently from OS libraries and kernel?

Tags: windows, filesystems, disk, mc

Does the windows version of **Midnight Commander (MC)** work independently from Windows libraries? I mean does it have it's own way of reading data off the disk or is it using the OS's abilities?
If it's not independent do you know of any file manager that is? (Is it possible?)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want MC to access the HDD controller directly? If no, you'll deal with Windows file system driver stack no matter what file manager you use.

Comment: Yeb, I want it to access the controller directly. Is that possible?

Comment: @Auxiliary not in Windows. I.e. you can build your own driver set, but still those drivers will fit into driver model. However, what you want to do is obviously not the final goal. Maybe if you describe your goal (bypass some restrictions, grab information outside of the file system etc) we will be able to give more detailed answer.

Comment: you are right, I have not precisely described what I want, cos this was a question of a friend. But what it seems he was looking for is a file manager that is not dependent on the Win32 API or whatever the Windows Explorer uses.

Comment: @Auxiliary still the question is what for is such behavior needed and why not use Win32 API.

Answer (score 1):

Only the windows kernel, and device drivers, can access the disks directly; all user mode programs must use the windows API (e.g. [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: JFYI: User-mode programs can load ntdll dynamically and import and use Nt* functions from there (eg. NtQueryDirectoryFile).

Comment: Yes, but I'd consider this to just be an undocumented function in the WIN32 API.

Comment: the functions I've mentioned are NOT win32 API, but Native API. These are different things. And those functions are perfectly documented.